# How to organize common logic code in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, mvvm

In ReactiveCocoa, if used with a logical judgment in a number of different pages, depending on the conditions to jump to the corresponding page, I feel this is not appropriate to judge where to put seemingly alone extracted passed many parameters, but also improves coupling.

For example, in a number of different pages I need to determine whitch page I will go according to the balance of the account,

```
 if the balance is not enough
       jump to the Top-Page; 
 else
     jump to the purchase page;
 if not logged in
      go to the login page;
```

The judge used on multiple pages it should determine how the use of such logic ReactiveCocoa organizations this code?